# How to the top N value for each division_id in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plsql

I have a table `worker` with columns `id, name, salary, division_id` and I need to display the workers with the top 3 salaries in each division. Here is sample data for table worker:

```
insert into worker values (1, 'Joe', 70000, 1);
insert into worker values (2, 'Henry', 80000, 2);
insert into worker values (3, 'Sam', 60000, 2);
insert into worker values (4, 'Max', 90000, 1);
insert into worker values (5, 'Janet', 69000, 1);
insert into worker values (6, 'Randy', 85000, 1);
insert into worker values (7, 'Jordan', 70000, 4);
insert into worker values (8, 'Adam', 69000, 3);
insert into worker values (9, 'David', 76000, 4);
insert into worker values (10, 'Moses', 68000, 4);
insert into worker values (11, 'Solomon', 55000, 4);
insert into worker values (12, 'Cloe', 38000, 3);
insert into worker values (13, 'Sarah', 88000, 3);
insert into worker values (14, 'Deb', 92000, 3);
insert into worker values (15, 'Lea', 98000, 4);
commit;
```

[image: Table WORKER sample data]

For the above sample data my query should return the following rows:
[image: Query result for sample data]

Note: division 2 has only 2 rows because it has only 2 rows in sample data.

The query should be in **Oracle** or **PostgreSQL**.

I know I can limit the number of rows with Oracle's `ROWNUM` or Postgres `LIMIT` keyword, but it doesn't help me here as I need to retrieve 3 rows or less for each `division_id`.

My query should be efficient as possible because the number of rows in `workers` can be huge (I don't know the exact row count).

In my solution, I am using a CURSOR and `FOR my_rec IN my_cursor` to scan the result-set and print only the first 3 rows or fewer for every `division_id`.  This solution gives me the complexity of **O(N)**, and I am hoping to find a better solution, maybe solve it with a single query without the use of `CURSOR`.

```
DECLARE
   CREATE CURSOR my_cursor IS
      SELECT division_id, name AS worker, salary
         FROM worker
         ORDER BY division_id, salary desc;
   division_id NUMBER;
   row_count_per_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR my_rec IN my_cursor LOOP
      -- If first iteration then initialize variables
      IF (row_num = 0) THEN
         division_id := myRec.division_id;
         row_count_per_id := 1;
      END IF;

      -- row_num can't be 0 at this point
      IF (division_id = myRec.division_id) THEN
         IF (row_count_per_id < 3) THEN
            -- Print first record of the new division_id
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('division_id = ' || myRec.division_id || 
                                 ', Worker = ' myRec.worker ||
                                 ', salary = ' myRec.salary;
            row_count_per_id := row_count_per_id + 1;
         END IF;
      ELSE
         -- division_id has changed from the previous row
         -- Add the first row of new division_id 
         division_id = myRec.division_id;
         row_count_per_id := 1;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('division_id = ' || myRec.division_id || 
                              ', Worker = ' myRec.worker ||
                              ', salary = ' myRec.salary;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Corrected and updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a query with `row_number`

```
WITH c AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY division_id ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rn
   FROM worker
)
SELECT *
  FROM c
WHERE rn <= 3
```

Depending on whether you want salaries that are equal receive the same rank and 
be given sequential rank or otherwise, you may use **`RANK`** or **`DENSE_RANK`** in place of `ROW_NUMBER`